# Checking the names of elements from an array of objects selected by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner in js and jquery library. I'd like to get an array of input fields with a particular name, and validate input. Each of my input fields have a name like NS[0], NS[1] etc. The total number of fields will have to be determined by the code, since the fields are generated by javascript.

I know that I can have jquery address the individual object like this:

`$("input[name=NS\\[0\\]]").val()` for `<input type="text" name="NS[0]">`.

However, how can I get an array of all these similiar elements, from NS[0] to NS[x] where x has to be determined based on how many fields have been generated? I already have other fields with different name patterns sharing the same css class, so using class is not an option. These boxes are in a particular div area, but in the same area are other input fields, so choosing all input boxes of the same area selects them as well.

In other words, how do I use jquery to check the name of each input field, after getting the entire array of input fields, to check each individual name?

Since I have input fields of various names in the area determined by the table id CNTR1, I would select them with `$('#CNTR1 input')`. I can also select individual fields by using `$("input[name=]")`. However, what I want to do, is to select everything under `$('#CNTR1 input')`, and then run a loop on their names, checking whether the names match a predetermined criteria. How can I do that?

The html code:

```
<table class="table" id="cnservers">
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Preference</th> 
        <th>Value</th> 
        <th>Name</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr id="CNTR0"> 
    <td>CNAME</td><td><input type="text" name="CN_PREF[0]" value=""></td><td>
    <input type="text" name="CN_VAL[0]" value=""></td><td>
    <input type="text" name="CN_NAME[0]" value="">  
    <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DelField(this.id);" id="CN_D0" >
        <span class="btn-label">Delete  
    </span>
    </a>            
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addField('cnservers','CN',10);" id="CN_A0" >
        <span class="btn-label">Add     
    </span>     

    </td></tr>      
</table>

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm0Jq.jpg
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Please include the wrapping ``table`` elements , and close your ``tr``. A jsfiddle of your code would help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must be missing something. Is there a reason you can't use the http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/?

```
$('#CNTR1').find('input[name^="NS"]')
```

Regarding,

> However, what I want to do, is to select everything under $('#CNTR1 input'), and then run a loop on their names, checking whether the names match a predetermined criteria. How can I do that?

```
$("#CNTR1 input").each(function(index, elem) { 
    var $elem = $(elem),
        name = $elem.attr('name');

    var nameMatchesCondition = true; // replace with your condition 
    if (nameMatchesCondition) {
        // do something!
    }   
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

Well, `id` is still an attribute of an html element. So you could do `$('[id^="CNTR1"]')` ... The value of the `id` attribute of an element doesn't contain the `#`. It's only part of the css/jquery selector. When using attribute style selectors, you don't need it. Though I can't comment on the performance of this.

Ideally, you want to attach a second class, say `js-cntr` to all elements that you created with an `id` starting with `CNTR`. Even though different name pattern elements may already have one class, that class is for styling. There is no stopping you from attaching custom classes purely for selection via js. This is an accepted thing to do and which is why the class name starts with `js-`, to denote that its purely for use via js for selection.

Comment: How can I address the beginning of #CNTR1, looking for something like `#^CNTR`. Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML

```
<table id="CNTR1">
  <tr>
   <td>CNAME</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="CN_PREF[1]" id="CN_IN[1]"></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="CN_VAL[1]"></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="CN_NAME[1]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#CNTR1 input").each(function() { 
      console.log($(this).attr("name"));
      // Match With predetermined criteria      
   });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, with a filter function:

```
filterCritera = /^CN_NAME\[/; // or whatever your criteria is

var inputs = $('#CNTR0 input');

// you could also cache this filter in a variable
inputs.filter(function(index){
    return filterCritera.test(this.name);
}).css('background','red');
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/okifan/1/edit)

The markup you posted does not the markup described in your question ( it does not contain `NS[0]`) but you can substitute it in the reguluar expression above.